# How to show swatches on category page in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

I was trying to show configurable color swatches on category listing page but unable to get it, I used below code but it just shows the name of color but I want to show swatches same as on product detail page,

Below code shows only color name which I have tried,

```
<?php if($_product->isConfigurable()): ?>
      <?php $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product) ?>
      <?php if(count($attributes)): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach($attributes as $att): ?>
          <?php $pAtt=$att->getProductAttribute();
            //get the child products
            $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
            $frontValues =array() ?>
           <ul>
           <?php foreach($allProducts as $p): ?>
             <?php if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue; ?>
             <?php $out=$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()); ?>
             <?php $frontValues[$out]=$out; ?>
           <?php endforeach ?>
            <li><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $frontValues) ?></li>
           </ul>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
      <?php endif ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product) ?>
```

to

```
<?php $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductAttributes($_product); ?>
```

Comment: Already used it in next loop but not working